# Did yfinance stop working? It's returning 404 after calling the info function

Tags: http-status-code-404, yfinance

I'm trying to make a finance tool using yfinance, however, I ran into the issue where I get a 404 Client Error whenever I try to use the

```
yf.Ticker(stock).info
```

The url at hand is `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quoteSummary/TSLA?modules=financialData&modules=quoteType&modules=defaultKeyStatistics&modules=assetProfile&modules=summaryDetail&ssl=true`  and I can't access it either from my PC or anywhere else...

Tried changing the user agent with no avail, perhaps it's an issue on their side?

Comment: Having this same problem, can't seem to find a solution. Any updates? I'm thinking about just switching APIs at this point, yFinance is super buggy.

Comment: Funnily enough I have this problem only with jupyter. I tried running his on Google Colab and it worked just fine. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378634/ticker-info-throws-error-in-jupyter-but-not-google-colab

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue the last week and it turns out updating yfinance did the trick:

```
pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

from: [Did yfinance and yahoo_fin for Python stop working recently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68218506/did-yfinance-and-yahoo-fin-for-python-stop-working-recently?rq=2)