# Ticker.info throws error in jupyter but not Google Colab

Tags: python, yfinance

The following code used worked fine in jupyter but stopped working last week,

```
import yfinance as yf
ltam = 'AAPL'
ticker = yf.Ticker(ltam)
ticker.info
```

The error thrown is,

```
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=financialData&modules=quoteType&modules=defaultKeyStatistics&modules=assetProfile&modules=summaryDetail&ssl=true
```

However, the above code continues to work on Google Colab.

Oddly all the pricing calls such as `yf.download` continue to work fine in jupyter. So this error seems to be confined to `Ticker.info` only.

I have a script that pulls in data for 20 odd tickers 3 times a week, so I don't think it's an excessive usage issue.

Both jupyter and Google Colab are using the same version of yfinance - 0.2.31.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I have this issue in google colab. I have not tried it in jupyter, but I 100% get the same error using google colab.

Comment: That's strange - Colab works fine for me. It looks right reading this thread https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1729 that it's related to the IP address. My jupyter IP address is in the UK whereas Google Colab is in the US.